# Facebook Open Graph not returning all results for Books.Read?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When using the Facebook Open Graph explorer, I run the following, to get a list of my books read.
/706685881/books.reads?limit=25&offset=0

This returns only 5 results, even though I have more books read than that, and I've explicitly requested up to 25 results. Following the paging link to the (theoretical) more results, shows a page with no more results.

here's my output of the query:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "data": {
        "book": {
          "id": "452418224806835", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Fantastic-Voyage/452418224806835", 
          "type": "books.book", 
          "title": "Fantastic Voyage"
        }
      }, 
      "id": "10151871872740882"
    }, 
    {
      "data": {
        "book": {
          "id": "106151566083577", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Andromeda-Strain/106151566083577", 
          "type": "books.book", 
          "title": "The Andromeda Strain"
        }
      }, 
      "id": "10151870390740882"
    }, 
    {
      "data": {
        "progress": [
          {
            "timestamp": 1388668020, 
            "percent_complete": 0
          }, 
          {
            "timestamp": 1392949225, 
            "percent_complete": 100
          }
        ], 
        "book": {
          "id": "10150233066083545", 
          "url": "http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10664113-a-dance-with-dragons", 
          "type": "good_reads:book", 
          "title": "A Dance with Dragons (A Song of Ice and Fire, #5)"
        }
      }, 
      "id": "10151867499170882"
    }, 
    {
      "data": {
        "progress": [
          {
            "timestamp": 1391350736, 
            "percent_complete": 0
          }, 
          {
            "timestamp": 1392569208, 
            "percent_complete": 100
          }
        ], 
        "book": {
          "id": "1390736374489290", 
          "url": "http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18405477-city-of-the-sun", 
          "type": "good_reads:book", 
          "title": "City of the Sun"
        }
      }, 
      "id": "10151860185710882"
    }, 
    {
      "data": {
        "book": {
          "id": "526531387368738", 
          "url": "http://apps.facebook.com/bookscout/?currworkid=9000000000133742", 
          "type": "books.book", 
          "title": "Gates of Fire"
        }
      }, 
      "id": "10151226827780882"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/706685881/books.reads?fields=data&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=10151226827780882"
  }
}
```

Anybody seeing what I am doing wrong?